# How can I represent a block will be executed polynomial time with package algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, polynomials

I want to represent an algorithm where a subsection must be repeated polynomial time. I am using algorithm package. I want to represent something like:

```
...
repeat polynomial time
     state 1
     state ..
     if cnd then return 1
return 0
```

I wrote the following but the repeat part does not look as I want:

```latex
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{RAFT Game}
    \label{alg:sur}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Function{RaftGame}{${\cal A}_0,{\cal A}_1$}
        \State  $k\leftarrow$ \Call{Gen}{$1^\lambda$};
        \Repeat \State Polynomial Time
            \State $t \leftarrow {\cal A}^{UserIssue(k,.,.)}_0(1^\lambda)$; 
            \State $t' \leftarrow {\cal A}^{ServiceIssue(k,.,.)}_1(t)$; 
            \If{$Ver(k,t') = 1$}
                \State return $1$; 
            \EndIf
        \State return $0$
        \EndFunction
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: I am not aware of any particular mechanism to do that. Why do you need it? If you are using pseudocode, you can just write it like you wrote in your post. If you are using a proper programming language, then it surely has the syntax for that?

Comment: How can I adjust the indentation?

Comment: @Reza: See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/168244)

Comment: @Reza: You can write the procedure using `\Procedure{..} ... \EndProcedure` (by also adding `\usepackage{algpseudocode}` to your preamble). But your question now is still not clear.